# capturar cualquier evento en un activitty

Tags: java, android

Quisiera saber cómo puedo capturar un evento (sea un click o un tap en la pantalla algo que genere una acción) en cualquier parte de un `Activity`. Esto con el fin de verificar primero si hay algo activado para dejar proseguir la acción o detenerla.

Comment: Buenas, no dejas muy claro que eventos quieres detectar

Comment: buenas, de ante mano gracias por tu tiempo.

lo que quiero es capturar cualquier evento antes de que sea procesado o un tap que no genere evento esto con el fin de sacar un progress dialog

Comment: Hola diego, puedes agregar lo que haz intentado editando tu pregunta para poder ayudarte, por desgracia tu pregunta puede catalogarse como demasiado amplia o que no esta claro lo que se pregunta.

Comment: @Webserveis yo creo que lo que quiere es tener un listener general para cualquier evento que sucede en el `Activity` y luego poder aplicar una acción. Esto comúnmente se resuelve con decoradores, una solución particular en Java suele ser AspectJ a menos que la tecnología ya lo soporte p.e. Servlets vía Servlet Filters.

Comment: @Webserveis Pienso que eso sería mas bien con un onTouchListener.

Comment: Diego, trata de probar con dispatchTouchEvent(), revisa mi respuesta. Te recomiendo cuando preguntes trata de poner que has intentado y trata de ser más especifico, porque generalmente este tipo de preguntas son cerradas :(, saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias a todos y claro que si colocare todo lo que he intentado para esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas detectar un click en una vista (TextView, Button, etc) únicamente detectas el click a travez de un `OnTouchListener`:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //Aquí muestras información, el clic de la vista fue efecutado.
        return false;
    }
});
```

Pero lo que deseas realizar, puedes lograrlo con un GestureListener o simplemente implementando este método dentro de tu activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    Log.i(TAG, "Se ha realizado un click dentro de la Activity");
    return false;
}
```